# Zooming Out and large scale mesh

Tags: mesh, interface, transforms

When I zoom out the display goes completely gray, and I lose sight of my mesh and the grid floor. Is there a way to fix this? This also occurs when I scale my mesh incredibly large; eventually it gets "lost" in the gray background.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're having trouble with viewport clipping, which by default is from 0.01 meters to 1000 meters.  Go to the Sidebar (upper right of the 3D viewport, sometimes called “the N Panel”) > View tab > Clip Start and End settings.

[image]

A similar issue can happen with rendering if the camera's clip start and end (0.1 meters to 100 meters by default) are insufficient to the scene.